# Large (but representable) integers get parsed as doubles by NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, parsing, uint64

I've been using the following method to parse NSString's into NSNumber's:

```c
// (a category method on NSString)
-(NSNumber*) tryParseAsNumber {
  NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
  [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
  return [formatter numberFromString:self];
}
```

And I had tests verifying that this was working correctly:

```
test(@"".tryParseAsNumber == nil);
...
test([(@NSUIntegerMax).description.tryParseAsNumber isEqual:@NSUIntegerMax]);
...
```

The max-value test started failing when I switched to testing on an iPhone 6, probably because NSUInteger is now 64 bits instead of 32 bits. The value returned by the formatter is now the double `1.844674407370955e+19` instead of the uint64_t `18446744073709551615`.

Is there a built-in method that succeeds exactly for all int64s and unsigned int64s, or do I have to implement one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[trudyscousin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25964000/52239) allowed me to figure it out.

`NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:` is capable of parsing with full precision, but it lets some bad inputs by (e.g. "88ffhih" gets parsed as 88). On the other hand, `NSNumberFormatter numberFromString:` always detects bad inputs but loses precision. They have opposite weaknesses.

So... just do both. For example, here's a method that should parse representable NSUIntegers but nothing else:

```objective-c
+(NSNumber*) parseAsNSUIntegerElseNil:(NSString*)decimalText {
    // NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString is good at noticing bad inputs, but loses precision for large values
    // NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString has perfect precision, but lets bad inputs through sometimes (e.g. "88ffhih" -> 88)
    // We use both to get both accuracy and detection of bad inputs
    NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    if ([formatter numberFromString:decimalText] == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSNumber* value = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:decimalText];

    // Discard values not representable by NSUInteger
    if (![value isEqual:@(value.unsignedIntegerValue)]) {
        return nil;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
+ [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:]
+ [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:]
```

Have you tried these?

**EDIT**

I'm not at all certain what it is you'd ultimately do with your instances of `NSNumber`, but consider that `NSDecimalNumber` seems to do exactly what you want:

```
NSDecimalNumber *decNum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"18446744073709551615"];
NSLog(@"%@", decNum);
```

which yields:

```
2014-09-21 15:11:25.472 Test[1138:812724] 18446744073709551615
```

Here's another thing to consider: `NSDecimalNumber` "is a" `NSNumber`, as it's a subclass of the latter. So it would appear that, whatever you can do with `NSNumber`, you can do with `NSDecimalNumber`.